# PHP site problems

Tags: php

My code of file.php:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['filename']) OR $_GET['filename'] == NULL) {
    print("Error!");
    exit();
}
$_GET['filename'] = htmlentities($_GET['filename'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
session_start();

include_once("/var/www/html/get.php");

for($i = 0; $i < $GLOBALS['files']['ile']; $i++) {

    if($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['name'] == $_GET['filename']) {
        if($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['priv'] == NULL OR $GLOBALS['files'][$i]['owner'] == $_SESSION['id'] OR (isset($_SESSION['privs']) AND in_array($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['priv'], $_SESSION['privs']))) {
            if(file_exists($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['loc'])) {
                header("Content-length: ".filesize($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['loc']));
                header("Content-type: ".mime_content_type($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['loc']));
                readfile($GLOBALS['files'][$i]['loc']);
            } else {
                print("Can't find that file!");
            }
        }

    }

}

?>
```

In get.php file, I loads (from database) information about files I wanted to have access using that file above in site.

```
$_SESSION['privs'] //it's an array that holds privileges, i.e: site.priv.mess
$GLOBALS['files'] //holds info about all files that user can load, i.e: $GLOBALS['files'][0]['name'] is a name of first file in array
$GLOBALS['files'][0]['loc'] //holds info about first file localisation
$GLOBALS['files']['ile'] // holds sizeof($GLOBALS['files'])
```

With pictures that works well, but if I try to load larger file, i.e. video that weights 300MB, then file loads, all looks good, but if I reloads site, it won't work anymore...
I tried to delete my cookies in browser (to change my session ID) and it works... But what can I do to make it works better?

EDIT: On Firefox all looks good, only freezes on Chrome :(

EDIT2: Closing session with: session_write_close(); before reading file fixed my curse :P Thanks y'all

Comment: the files you are sending is too big for your server.

Answer (score 3):

Check your php.ini or use `phpinfo()` to check your values for `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`. Maybe also check the max execution time of the php script.

Comment: i have default values. Do I need to change them to make it works?

Comment: i changed them and now when i open that file in new tab, freezes site on other tabs (only on that address, on other still works). It looks like that freezes only session

Comment: try with another browser when u think it is only the session-freez. :)

Comment: yes, you can use ini_set() for this or you change the values in the php.ini directly. Can your internet bandwith handle the data? Or is your server fast enough, or are you testing it locally?

Comment: I testing it and locally, and externally. And I see it freezes all session on any type of connection. But It's most intresting i discovered, that on local connection video loadings nicely (still session lag), but on external it won't work for me. My friend said that on his computer all works perfectly. So I dunno what to do now.